# Regarding reading files which contain UTF-8 character

Tags: r, unicode

I have a csv file including chinese character saved with UTF-8.

> 项目    价格
>     电视    5000

The first row is header, the second row is data. In other words, it is  one by two vector.

I read this the file as follows:

```
amatrix<-read.table("test.csv",encoding="UTF-8",sep=",",header=T,row.names=NULL,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

However, the output including the unknown marks for the header, i.e.,X.U.FEFF

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) sometimes found in Unicode text files. I'm guessing you're on Windows, since that's the only popular OS where files can end up with them.

What you can do is read the file using `readLines` and remove the first two characters of the first line.

```
txt <- readLines("test.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
txt[1] <- substr(txt[1], 3, nchar(txt[1]))
amatrix <- read.csv(text=txt, ...)
```

Comment: Hi, the approach works, thanks.  By the way, after typing txt <- readLines("test.csv", encoding="UTF-8"), I directly type txt, but nothing will appear on the screen. which kind of object is txt?

Comment: It's just a vector of strings, one for each line in your file. They might be very long strings though, depending on what the file contains.

Comment: I posted a figure in the following post, I do not quite understand why txt[1] output nothing even though it is not empty, thanks.